# Show a webform input if user selects certain option from select list?

Tags: webforms

Im making a webform with a select list. If you chose a certain option in the select list I need a text input field be be revealed.

Can this be done by Drupal or should I write some jQuery to show / hide the input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update to a newer version of Webform where [webform_conditional](http://drupal.org/project/webform_conditional) has been merged.

> Description: This modules enhances the existing Conditional Rules of
>   the Webform Module. It adds the ability to make components dependent
>   on select components(i.e. listboxes, radio buttons, and checkboxes)
>   that appear on the same page.
>
> **Important** As of Webform version 7.x-4.0-alpha2 this module has been merged into Webform and is no longer necessary. The 7.x-2.x
>   version of this module handles this upgrade. See: #1616376: Create
>   Migration to Webform 4.x

Then when you make a webform node you will have additional local task labeled `conditionals`. Once you've added form fields to the webform -- you can set conditions using the administrative form found there.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it using Javscript and hide the text field with CSS

Using a form_preprocess, add an attribute to fire your JS event.

This might be a helpful link: [How to make form buttons call only javascript?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/16818/how-to-make-form-buttons-call-only-javascript)