# Speech API Javascript and Drupal Forms

Tags: forms, javascript

I'm using WebSpeech API to allow users speech recognition on my site. I'm using example 3 on this page: https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/speech-api/raw-file/tip/speechapi.html.

My code looks like this:

```
function _google_speech_speak_form($form, &$form_state) {
$modulepath = drupal_get_path('module','google_speech');
$form['textarea'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Speak It'),
    '#prefix' => '<div id="api">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
   );
$form['button'] = array(
    '#type' => 'button',
    '#attributes' => array('onclick' => 'return (false);'),
    '#value' => t('Click to Speak'),
   );
$form['submitt'] = array(
    '#type' => 'button',
    '#value' => t('Save'),
   );
$form['#after_build'] = array('_google_speech_speak_after_build');
return $form;}

function _google_speech_speak_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
$speechkey = $form_state['values']['textarea'];
drupal_set_message($speechkey);
echo "test";}


function _google_speech_speak_after_build($form, &$form_state) {
drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'google_speech').'/webspeech.js');
return $form;}
```

Webspeech.js:

```
 Drupal.behaviors.[google_speech] = function(context) {
 $('#edit-button').click(function() {
  var recognizing;
 var recognition = new webkitSpeechRecognition();
recognition.continuous = true;
reset();
recognition.onend = reset;

recognition.onresult = function (event) {
  for (var i = resultIndex; i < event.results.length; ++i) {
    if (event.results.final) {
      textarea.value += event.results[i][0].transcript;
    }
  }
}

function reset() {
  recognizing = false;
  button.innerHTML = "Click to Speak";
}

function toggleStartStop() {
  if (recognizing) {
    recognition.stop();
    reset();
  } else {
    recognition.start();
    recognizing = true;
    button.innerHTML = "Click to Stop";
  }
  }
 });
 };
```

I referred to this question: [How to make form buttons call only javascript?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/16818/how-to-make-form-buttons-call-only-javascript)
The "toggle" button is not refreshing the page (which is good) but it's also not toggling speech recognition like it should. There are no errors on the screen or in the logs. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

To properly add JS or CSS to a form you use the `#attached` array key. See this similar question answered already here with links to documentation. Then your JS button should work.

https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/70036/3279

Comment: This doesn't resolve the real issue here: the form is being submitted when the "button" is clicked. This refreshes the page and negates the script toggle action.